# My app crashes after I set global variable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a _MainViewController and in its view, I have 2 subviews,

1. _MenuViewController.view which shows menu and is always at front.
2. Another view behined _MenuViewController.view which changes
   according to what has been selected in the menu. So, the
   _MenuViewController.view is an overlay.

Now, in order to change the behind view, I have created this function:

```
UIViewController * ReplaceSubViews(UIViewController *present,NSString *vcid,NSString *storyboard_id)
{ //present: present 'behined' view, 
 //vcid: storyboard if of view to replace with behined
    if(storyboard_id==nil) storyboard_id=@"UI";
    [present.view removeFromSuperview];

     UIStoryboard *storybrd=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboard_id bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* future;
    if(vcid==nil)
        future= [storybrd instantiateInitialViewController];
    else
        future= [storybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcid];

    [_MainViewController.view addSubview:future.view];
    [_MainViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:_MenuViewController.view];
    return future;
}
```

Now, a button event touchUpInside calls the function.
After replacement, it makes its own viewcontroller's instance as nil.
This was the viewcontroller's instance(global variable):

```
UIViewController *_MyViewController;
```

Now, button's action:

```
- (IBAction)ShowARView:(id)sender {
   ReplaceSubViews(self, nil, @"CamController");
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;


    _MyViewController=nil; //App Crashes on this

}
```

I even tried delaying the nullifying process by:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            _MyViewController=nil; //This is basically self


 });
```

But still the app crashes. Please help.
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1qqg7g2Hx3WAdC7SfGB4XpNDjuyNzZqFKlf55zED5x88/pub?w=272&h=256

My Code is ARC enabled.

Comment: Show the stack trace from the crash, please.

Comment: What does your error in console say?

Comment: OMG! Who have taught you all take root view from one viewcontroller and add it to another view? This is failure from the beginning.

Comment: And also to use global variables.  Time for a rethink...

Comment: @PhillipMills Added the stack trace.

Comment: @JohnDoe The console says nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use one ViewController and change it's view as a kind of navigation, that's not what view controllers are about.
Every (root)view should have its own controller. Use a Navigation Controller or something, I think your navigation isn't done very well.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it in a span of time.